# physicsBody rotation limitation

Tags: objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I've got the following node set as follow.

```
box.physicsBody.allowsRotation = YES;
```

No mater what force applies to this box, I want it to never fall down or rotate more than a certain angle, just like a tree or a spring that might bend all the way down but has a tendency to go back to it's initial angle or position.

Is there a any trick or method to that?

I was thinking maybe joining an invisible un-rotatable physics body under the box and use a joint spring method for that which I have no Idea how that works!

Or, maybe there be a trick to play with the pivot. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `update:` method you will have to continuously check the desired node's properties. In your case it is going to be the `zRotation` property of your node.

Add this code in your `update:` method:

```
if(yourNode.zRotation > 0.5)
    yourNode.zRotation = 0.5;

if(yourNode.zRotation < -0.5)
    yourNode.zRotation = -0.5;
```

Change the 0.5 value to your desired value or replace it with a `static const float`.

Comment: Thanks sangony, worked fine, specially when I replaced it with an action and a little time interval.